# Get all IDs in the div

Tags: jquery, html

I have a `<div></div>` where user are allow to drag items(Text,Image) into the `<div>` area. What can I do to get all the id in the `<div>`?

HTML

```
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> 

  <div id="TextBoxesGroup">
    <div id="TextBoxDiv1">
      <label class="draggable ui-widget-content clickableLabel" id="label1" >Text Here</label>
      <input id="textbox1" class="clickedit" type="text" class="draggable" class="ui-widget-content" placeholder="Text Here"/>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <img src="../../test.png" height="150" width="150" class="draggable" class="ui-widget-content" id="qr"/>

  <br/>

</div>
```

Comment: please share some relevant code to explain your problem

Comment: This will definitely get down votes if you don't explain it well (I did not vote it down). Revise it please.

Comment: okay. are need get all id's  or image and text from div ?

Comment: Explain what you mean by the *"id to know all the items in the `<div>`"*. Do you mean there are elements inside that have an id? Please give an HTML example with what you would like to get from it, this question is unclear.

Comment: Right now it's not really very clear what you're asking. Are you looking for all sub-elements of a `div` or only direct children? Or are you looking for divs by position rather than DOM hierarchy?

Comment: if u have to get only id which is dragged to div tag then u can get by `event.target.id`

Comment: `$("#mainDiv").find('[id]')`?

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery way:

```
var ids = $.map($("div [id]"), function (item) {
    return $(item).attr("id");
});
```

The Javascript way (or one of the ways):

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll("div [id]");
var ids = Array.prototype.reduce.call(items, function (arr, elem) {
    arr.push(elem.id);
    return arr;
}, []);
```

Comment: It is not working. It prompt me id outside of the div and not inside